# Relative Homology (Question about Example 2 in Munkres)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

[image]

I have no problems for $p=0$ case and for $p\geq 2$ it is quite obvious since $C_p(K,v)=C_p(K),\forall p\geq 2$. Now the tricky is for $p=1$. Since the elements of the kernel now not anly map to $0$ but also map to $nv,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. So, $Z_1(K,v)\neq Z_1(K)$ even $B_1(K,v)=B_1(K)$. So how could $H_1(K,v)=H_1(K)$?

Comment: Note that for each $1$-chain $c$, the sum of the coefficients of $\partial c$ is $0$. So when $\partial c \in C_0(v)$, then $n$ is $0$, thus $C_1(K,v) = C_1(K)$ (when $C$ denotes the group of cycles, aka the kernel of the boundary map, I'm more used to $Z$ for this kernel and $C$ is the chain group).

Comment: @StefanHamcke Oh sorry I made a typo, that should be $Z$. Why is the sum of the coefficients is $0$? I don't quite get it

Comment: @StefanHamcke Oh yeah... I know. Yeah, that's right the sum is 0. Thanks Stefan :)